# Python sorting based on first and last character in a string

Tags: python-2.7

Im taking an online beginner course through google on python 2, and I cannot figure out the answer to one of the questions. Here it is and thanks in advance for your help!

```
# A. match_ends
# Given a list of strings, return the count of the number of
# strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first
# and last chars of the string are the same.
# Note: python does not have a ++ operator, but += works.

def match_ends(words):
  a = []
  for b in words:

return
```

I tried a few different things. This is just where i left off on my last attempt, and decided to ask for help. I have spent more time thinking about this than i care to mention

Answer (score 0):

```
def match_ends(words):
    a = []
    for b in words:
        if (len(b) > 2 and b[0] == b[len(b)-1]):
            a.append(b)
    return a  


def match_ends2(words):
    return [x for x in words if len(x) > 2 and x[0] == x[len(x)-1]]

print(match_ends(['peter','paul','mary','tibet']))
print(match_ends2(['peter','paul','mary','tibet']))
```